# PHP login and redirect

Tags: php, html, logging, post, input

The following PHP code echoes error before entering mistaken password and gives - Notice: Undefined index: password

```
<?php 
    //Specify password here
    $pass='pass';
    if($_POST['password']!=$pass)
    {
        echo ("<div class='errmg'>Error</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        header( 'Location: admin.php' ) ;
    }
?>
```

Below I've the following HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            Enter password:
            <input name="password" type="password">
            <input name="send" type="submit" value="Log in!">
        </form>
```

Please help me to repair these errors and make this login-redirect better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't submitted the form, `$_POST` is empty, so there's no `$_POST['password']`, just as the error says. Always check whether variables that may or may not be set exist before using them:

```
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['password'] == $pass) {
        header(…);
    } else {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 second faster than me on the submit button :P

Answer (score 1):

It means that $_POST['password'] isn't properly set. I'm not sure why, it looks find in your code. I would just see if it is set first and then see if it is correct.

```
   if(isset($_POST['password']) {
    if($_POST['password'] != $pass) {
        echo "<div class='errmg'>Error</div>";
    } else {
        header('Location: admin.php');
    }
}
```

Secondly, you should always close your html tags, both your input tags arent closed, to close them, add a "/>" at the end instead of just ">" like so:

```
<input name="password" type="password" />
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Log in!" />
```